# SharePoint 2010 DB Migration - Web App URL

Tags: migration, web-application

According to the following documentation, I should use the same URL for my Web application as I had in the 2007 version: "If you use a different URL, Microsoft Office applications might not be redirected correctly to the new URLs..." Could someone expand on this?

My 2007 version is still in use on the network as http...intranet and I want to set up the new 2010 version in the format http...intranet2. Is this not possible/advisable?

[Prepare the new SharePoint Server 2010 environment for a database attach upgrade](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263026.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to configure the 2010 environment the same http.//intranet address, then when it comes to migrate, you just change DNS to point http.//intranet to your new 2010 server.

Comment: I cannot have two identical URLs on the network. I'm trying to migrate to a test VM farm and find it hard to believe they would have this requirement...

Comment: Then you just configure it the same and modify your hosts file to point it to your test VM IP address.  Configuring it identically is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I'm not an admin, so bear with me. Right now the 2010 VM is named "intranet2", the 2007 machine is "intranet". I have installed SP2010 with the Web app named "intranet2". What should I do at this stage?

Comment: What PirateEric is saying is that your new SharePoint server should recognise http://intranet as itself by modifying the hosts file on that new server (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) put an entry in that for 127.0.0.1    intranet and then on that machine only you will be able to load the web application up as http://intranet. Do this for your database attach migration once thats finished alter the Alternate Access Mappings for http://intranet2

Comment: Thanks for the clarification pigeon. After I take the old intranet offline (post-migration), is AAM the only alternative at that stage?